# In which point differential $(Df)_p$ is zero?

Tags: analysis

Consider the differential $(Df)_p$ function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y)=x^2+(xy+1)^2$. In which point $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is it zero?

Should I find partial derivatives wrt to x and y and make them equal to zero? (i.e. $\bigtriangledown f(x,y)=\vec{0} $).

Comment: Bingo! If you use your suggestion, what point(s) do  you get?

Comment: I will give myself a free lunch :P?

Comment: One thing to be careful of, $(Df)_p$ which can be represented as the vector gradient $\nabla f(p)$ in your case won't equal the scalar $0$, but rather the $0$ vector; i.e., $\nabla f (p) = (0, 0)$.

Comment: Yes I forgot to write the arrow on the zero. Thanks